# How can I check if my IPV4 packet is a GENEVE packet?

Tags: c++, networking, packet, ipv4, packet-sniffers

What is the GENEVE protocol number?

For example GRE has a protocol number of 47.

Thanks,
Erez

Comment: A quick Google turned up https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-worley-nvo3-geneve-misc-00.html#rfc.section.3.2

Answer (score 1):

The [RFC-8926](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8926) defines the GENEVE.

As per the RFC, the protocol is based on UPD over IPv4 or IPv6, which means that the protocol will be set to `UDP = 17`

To recognize that this is GENEVE:

1. Packet will be UDP
2. Dest Port will be 6081
3. UDP Checksum will follow the rules described in the RFC